# spring-boot container not restarting after database-container booted

Tags: java, spring, docker

I am setting up CI for Gitlab right now. The goal is to deploy a docker container for a simple spring-boot application and an other container for the mariadb.

It is all working well except, that the docker-container is somehow not trying to restart after a couple of tries to connect with the database in the other container. It is then kind of stuck where it does nothing. Meanwhile the mariadb container is booted but the app container /spring is already stuck.

If i manually restart the spring-app container after the mariadb container booted, the problem is "solved".

I tried to change the java memory from `Xmx1g` to `Xmx2g` which didnt help.

I also tried to add the `continue-on-error: true`.

I also removed all docker container and images and tried it again. No success.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1' 

services: 
  mariadb:
    image: <...>
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "<...>:<...>"
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <...>
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: <...>

  app: 
    image: <...>
    restart: always 
    ports:
      - "<...>:<...>"
    container_name: app
    environment:
       - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=feature"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    links:
      - mariadb:db
```

Weird is, that `restart: always` is enabled but it somehow does not restart. I am clueless.

Comment: what is the state of your app container ?

Comment: "It is then kind of stuck where it does nothing" If the container doesn't fail docker wont restart it. Does it fail or just keeps running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I updated Spring to a newer version, from 2.1.4 to 2.1.6. Somehow, the version of Spring i used caused this problem.